# How do i write linked list as an object to a file

Tags: c++

In this function I am trying to write the information from the linked list to a file

```
class Employer: public People{

            void tryWrite(){

                ofstream file("Employer.dat",ios::out|ios::app| ios::binary);


                if(file.is_open()){


                    file<<getFirstName()<<" "<<getLastName()<<" " << companyName<<" "<<position<<" "<<getTelHome()<<" "<<getTelMobile()<<" " <<email<<" "<<getAddress()<< endl;

                    file.close();
                }

            }


    };
    #endif
```

This is the linked list manipulator for the employer class

At this point in the writeFile function I am trying to traverse through the link list and call the tryWrite function in Employer.h to write to the actual data in the link list to file

```
  class EmployerList
  {
    private:

        Employer *head;//employee pointer(head pointer)

    public:     

   void writeFile(){

     Employer *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {

            temp->tryWrite();//Employee's display method called here
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }


  }
```

In this read function I would like to read the data in the following order Name: Jane brown Company's name: Lime Position: clerk Address:
New Kingston Home#: 876-466-8778 Mobile #: 543-455-6344 Email: dumb@yahoo.com

But reading directly from the file the data is Jane brown Lime clerk
 New Kingston 876-466-8778 543-455-6344 dumb@yahoo.com

when it gets to the address it will display as: Address: New

instead of: Address: New Kingston

The null spaces is creating the issue and i do not know how to get it
 to do what i want

void TestRead(){

```
    ifstream tryRead("em.dat", ios::in|ios::binary);


    string Email,  cName, pos,fName,lName,addr, tHome,tMobile;


    while(tryRead>>fName>>lName>>cName>>pos>>addr>>tHome>>tMobile){

        cout<<"Name: "<<fName<<lName<<endl;
        cout<<"Comapny's Name: "<<cName<<endl;
        cout<<"Position: "<<pos<<endl;
        cout<<"Address: "<<addr<<endl;
        cout<<"Home#: "<<tHome<<endl;
        cout<<"Mobile#: "<<tMobile<<endl;

                      tryRead.close();
    }


} 


};
        #endif
```

This is main which populate the linked list with data

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "Employer.h"
    #include "EmployerList.h"

    using namespace std;

    void main()
    {

        EmployerList em;

        em.AddNode("nim@yahoo.com", "LIME", "Manager", "Tashauna", "Simon", "New Kingston", "876-985-8337", "876-405-3536");

        em.AddNode("ker@gmail.com", "NOKIA", "CEO", "Keric", "McDonald", "Europe", "0411-789-6548", "985-257-1111");
```

After the linked list is filled with data the write file function in EmployerList.h is called

```
        em.writeFile();

   em.TestRead(); 




        system("pause");

    }
```

Comment: It is hard to help you if you have to read through all that code. Don't post more code than necessary.

Comment: @Zyx2000 I took out the unnecessary codes

Comment: Did you copy and paste your question from an e-mail? Why are you putting > in front of your text? It's causing your text to appear as "quotes"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a linked list object to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854596/how-to-write-a-linked-list-object-to-a-file)

Answer (score 5):

I didn't read your code, because its irrelevant. The question is in the title, and that's what I'm answering.

Writing a linked list into a file means writing each member of the linked list into a file. Linked list is a chain of objects that point one to the next one, and when you want to dump it into a file - you just dump each of these objects one after another.

When you need to rebuild your linked list - you read each object from the file, and chain it in a new linked list in the same order (if you saved FIFO - make sure to rebuilt the same, not in reverse). Needless to mention, you should not be saving the pointers and reading them from the file back.

If the question is about something in that enormous chunk of code - you'll have to refine the question and minimize the code.

**edit**

After you kindly mentioned what the real problem is - then in your `tryWrite` you're opening the same file over and over again, overwriting whatever was there previously. Obviously, it will leave you with the one last object from the list in the end, because all the previous ones would be overwritten.

You should use `ios::out | ios::in | ios::ate` or `ios::out | ios::app`, to seek to the end of the existing data and add, instead of just `ios::out`.

Comment: yes the question is in the code, when i post previously the viewers were complaining that my code wont run and that i should post the whole code. the questions are the writeFile in EmloyerList.h and tryWrite function in Employer.h. I want to know how to write each linked list to the fiile

Comment: @TT you're overwriting your file every time. Fix it and you'll be good.

Comment: @liitleadv I edited the code and only include what is giving me trouble. review it again and see if it is clearer

Comment: I cant seem to get it to write both data to the file at once. without the ios::app it ony writes the last data to the file

Comment: @TT, I read your last comment and now I'm confused... You know what you should do, and you don't do it, and you wonder why it doesn't work?

Comment: this line does not ios::out | ios::in | ios::ate does not create a file...ios::out | ios::app does adds everything to the file..

Comment: @TT ios::in expects the file to be there, so if you're creating it at the first iteration - you should use the second option.

Comment: ok I see...now am having problems gettin the data to its correct spot..am going to edit my post and include it

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell without transcribing, compiling and running your code, there isn't anything fundamentally wrong with it. I would have extracted the ofstream out of the tryWrite() function, opened it once in writeFile() and pass it in as an argument, rather than opening and closing the file for each node in the linked list.

You MIGHT have some problems reading the linked list back in because you don't seem to do anything to scan for illegal characters in the data. You are using the space character as a delimiter, so you should be careful to make sure that any fields that you save to the file are first escaped (i.e. that you replace any space characters with some kind of escape sequence). Otherwise, when reading things back in, a wayward space could throw things off badly.

For future reference, if you are having problems with your code, rather than just listing all the code and asking what's wrong with it, you should probably try to at least describe what problems you're running into -- what is the output, where in the code do you think you are doing something wrong, etc.

Comment: @EdJ yeah you are right when i try read from the file i do have problems for example I want the address which should be "New Kingston" when I read from the file all I get back is "New" for the address instead of "New Kingston".