# C linked list - Write pointer to file

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct transgressor
{
    int priority;
    Record record;
    struct transgressor *next;
    int position;
    int hasNext;
}Transgressor;
```

I need to write it to file. Problem is with `struct transgressor *next` part because it's pointer. How can I dereference it, or organize struct different, so I can write it and after read from file?

Comment: you must write it with its attributes one by one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a linked list object to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854596/how-to-write-a-linked-list-object-to-a-file)

Comment: You can write it, but it will have no meaning to the reader. (except, maybe for the program that wrote it)

Comment: And then rebuild the next pointer when you'll deserialize the file. Since a pointer is a reference to memory address, it makes no sense to persist it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in saving the pointer to file. Since you already have a `position` variable in your struct, you can use that to help you re-create the list in memory instead when loading the list from file.

Answer (score 0):

Before you save anything to a file, you should specify (ideally as a written document) the format in which the data will be stored in the file at the byte level. Use an existing file format if there is one that's convenient, otherwise you have to design and specify your own.

Once you've decided on the format for the data at the byte level, write code to convert the structure to and from that format. What that format to the disk. Read that format from the disk.

There are no shortcuts that don't lead to pain and suffering.